# Node docx-templates library does not handle IF structure

Tags: node.js, templates, docx

I'm using the node-based [docx-templates](https://github.com/guigrpa/docx-templates) to create a word document from an spfx webpart.

I'm having issues defining the IF structure.
Below structure results in an SyntaxError.

> Error executing command '$question.type === 'text''. SyntaxError:
> Invalid or unexpected token

```
+++IF question.type === 'text' +++
...
+++END-IF+++
```

Following statement is passing, so it seems it cannot evaluate the '===' statement.
I tried with double and triple '='.

```
+++IF question.type +++
...
+++END-IF+++
```

The syntax is exact the same as in the [doc](https://github.com/guigrpa/docx-templates#if-and-end-if) but I can't find any [examples](https://github.com/guigrpa/docx-templates/tree/master/examples/example-node) using the IF.

I'm wondering if it may be a bug or am I overlooking something here.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
+++IF data.test_barchart_doc_gen.data != ``+++ 
+++IMAGE data.test_barchart_doc_gen+++ 
+++END-IF+++
```

> Usually `back-ticks` works for these cases in the DOCX templates